# Convert node application to executable file for linux, window & Mac

Tags: node.js

I have a nodeJS application, it has 2 routes containing views and one API.
what I need is to convert this to one file, so that client can just click on the file and run it.
I used npm pack, pkg module to do it but the issue is.

> It creates an executeable file but it runs only in project directory if I copy that to some other folder and run it fails, it needs other files.
>   I need to make only one file so that I can give it to anyone needed, instead of the folder containing node modules and other files along with the executeable file

Comment: I think you need to install pkg globally by npm install -g pkg

Comment: yes, I have installed pkg globally, it's not working.